# Does my PC need to execute DHCP in order to have an IP address?

Tags: ip, dhcp

This afternoon I read this from the book "Computer Networking - A Top-Down Approach":

*"When Bob first connects his laptop to the network, he can’t do anything (e.g.,
download a Web page) without an IP address. Thus, the first network-related action
taken by Bob’s laptop is to run the DHCP protocol to obtain an IP address, as well
as other information, from the local DHCP server".*

Now i have 2 questions:

1-Does this mean in order for my PC to have an IP it needs **always** to execute DHCP protocol ? (And so does that mean if my PC is offline i don`t have an IP? ).

2-The IP of my PC changes depending from the local DHCP server?

Answer (score 0):

1-Does this mean in order for my PC to have an IP it needs always to execute DHCP protocol ? (And so does that mean if my PC is offline i don`t have an IP? ).

The PC does not actually have to send a DHCP request to the router/modem/switch. It means then when your pc is offline is does not uses a connection to servers on the web. but the IP is also registerd in your PC when there was a DHCP request answered succesfull.

2-The IP of my PC changes depending from the local DHCP server?

The IP of your PC could change from the local DHCP server when the lease is expired

Answer (score -1):

1. Not totally necessary to "execute" DHCP protocol to have an IP, as you can have a static IP configured in your PC. Although you can't put any random IP, but only those that commit the Local Area Network configuration of your router.

I don't understand the second part of the point 1. You can be off the Internet and yet have an IP for local purposes. Does it answer your first question?

2. Yes